# How allow empty fields or alternative to solve undefined offset empty value?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a column in my database, but that column may have some empty field, when trying to save I get the title error in the fields that are empty.

I make the post with 2 arrays, it is a test, the first array contains the IDs of the questions, the second array contains the OPTION that was selected, but there may be an answer left blank, it is when trying to save this, I get the Title error I need to know if there is any way to fill in the empty values or any alternative that allows these empty fields.

```
$preg_id_array = $_POST['pregunta'];
$opcion_array  = $_POST['radio'];

 foreach ($preg_id_array as $p) 
   {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO detalle_resp(id_resp, preg_id) VALUES ('$id_resp','$p')";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    $index = $p;
        $q = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT respuesta FROM detalle_resp");

    while(list($p) = @mysqli_fetch_row($q)) 
         {          
            mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE detalle_resp SET respuesta ='".$opcion_array[$index]."' WHERE preg_id='$p'");
    }

}
```

Comment: To further explain why this was closed: [in order for all visitors to understand questions and answers, please only use English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) - however, there is a dedicated Spanish stackoverflow over on https://es.stackoverflow.com, so you may want to repost your question there.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Include the full error message you get in your question.